# .Net Standard Nuget install in Framework 4.5 project

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've created two projects that target .NetStandard 1.3 both of which I've created individual Nuget packages for. The Nuget packages are being installed into the same .Net Framework 4.6 project, however one installs fine but the other doesn't and give the following error:

> Could not install package 'PackageName 1.0.0'. You are trying to
>   install this  package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the  package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are  compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Everything looks the same in both projects in terms of the project settings so I'm unsure what is going wrong.

Any thoughts on what the problem could be?

Comment: I would take a look inside the .nupkg files and compare them to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

If your second library using internally some other packages with higher versions that are not compatible with v4.6, that might be the cause.

Comment: Thanks, however I've stripped it right back to basics so only the Standard library SDK is present but still got the problem.